# Problemas con el hook before usando Mocha para realizar tests de backend

Tags: nodejs, backend, test, mocha

Estoy testeando una aplicación con Mocha y al hacer "node helper_test.js" obtengo el siguiente error:

**¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?**

```
ReferenceError: before is not defined
```

Donde `before` es un hook de mocha y "helper_test.js" es un fichero de test en el que quiero empezar introduciendo un usuario a una base de datos de mongoDB.

fichero: helper_test.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
before(done => {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test_app', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
  });
  mongoose.connection
    .once('open', () => {

      const user1 = {
        _id: '6181608b936f234576a24d4d',
        role: 'FREEUSER_ROLE',
        status: true,
        active: false,
        lang: "ESP",
        username: "BaldanHero",
        email: "baldanhero@gmail.com",
        password: "12345678",
      }

      user1.save();

       done();
    })
    .on('error', error => {
      console.log('Error', error);
    });
});

after(async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en que lo intento lanzar usando el comando `node helper_test.js` y en realidad lo tengo que lanzar usando mocha.
1º Vamos al package.json y en scripts vamos a test y ponemos "mocha", de tal manera que quedaría así:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
```

Después hacemos `npm test` y ya se lanza el test.